# min value from table

Tags: mysql

```
$test2=mysql_query("SELECT min(substr(status,1) FROM railways");
while($test_array1=mysql_fetch_array($test2)){
echo "<pre>";
print_r($test_array1);
echo "</pre>"; 
}
```

what is the correct form of this query...need to get the min value from the table itself..

Comment: can you give the table definition

Comment: also please lemme know how to get the value for the min(substr(status,1)

Comment: Status has the following content :
w10,c34,c34,c10 and so on....

Comment: so status is varchar(20)?. I am looking  for the table definition So i know what we are working with. right off the bat you are just pulling the first character. So your sort is going to sort c,c,c,w

Comment: i guess i will be getting the numeric values only...(10,34,34...) while I use substr(status,1)...

Answer (score 0):

substr(status, 1) returns the string as it is ... mysql counts in strings from 1, not from 0.

if i got you right using substr(status,2) is what you are looking for.

best regards
phil

Comment: donno y but substr(status, 1) gives the numeric values for me. substr(status, 0) gives the entire string as it is.. is it a matter of the version used??? i m not sure

Comment: i'm using mysql 5.1 and substr(status, 0) returns an empty string. which version are you running?

since you extract the numeric value correctly, what is your difficulty now?

btw: why do you use a loop to print out the results? min(..) returns a single value.

Answer (score 0):

substr(status, 1) is going to give 'w21', but substr(status, 2) is going to give 21.  If you want to get the minimum and the pattern is DIGIT_NUMBER_NUMBER, you will use `min(substr(status, 2))`.  From this data set: w21, c33, d55, d11, it will pull the minimum number you want.